# tkinter combobox gets full focus and figure connection is lost

Tags: python, matplotlib, tkinter

Hi i have a problem when i use *fig.canvas.mpl_connect* with *tkinter combobox*. I am just connecting my figure to my keyboard. However when i use the combobox to select a color (the values of the combobox are just colors for my figure), and then i plot the figure, the connection is lost. However before i select a value from the combobox, the connection works. Bear in mind that if i don't choose any value and let the current one, it works. However if i pick a value, it doesn't (the focus goes on the combobox and when i press a keyboard key to print 'i can print this', i am writting on the combobox instead).

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg
from tkinter import ttk
import tkinter as tk
import matplotlib
win=tk.Tk()

def myplot():
    ax.plot([1,2,3,4,5,6],color=cb.get())
    canvas.draw()

def myfun(event):
    print('i can print this')


bt=tk.Button(win,text="plot",command=myplot);bt.grid(row=2,column=1)


cb=ttk.Combobox(win,state="readonly",values=['red','blue','green','yellow']);cb.grid(row=0,column=1)
cb.current(0)

fig,ax=plt.subplots()
canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig, master=win)
canvas.get_tk_widget().grid(row=0,column=0)
canvas.draw()

con=fig.canvas.mpl_connect('key_press_event',myfun)


win.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to bind to the entire window instead of just the figure:

```
# ~ con=fig.canvas.mpl_connect('key_press_event',myfun)
win.bind('<KeyPress>',myfun)
```

Comment: thanks for the response. It works, however if i print the data of the x axis (event.xdata), it says ''Event' object has no attribute 'xdata''

Comment: Ah right, the event is now a tkinter event, and as such it has no link to the figure anymore. You'll need to get that data some other way.

Comment: well yeah, that is the problem. I have the figure and i want to get the x axis data when i press a keyboard button after i select the color of it using a combobox and i plot it using a button. That is why i use fig.canvas.mpl_connect. If i don't use a combobox, it works. However the combobox does something and takes away the focus on the figure....

Comment: Yeah, that "something" is just being in focus. mpl_connect only works while the widget has focus. If you give focus to another widget it would have the same result. Just get the x_data from line.get_xdata() or (better) simply save it yourself in a convenient place.

Comment: emm no i am sorry, i need to use the fig.canvas.mpl_connect with combobox. Anyway thank you for your help!! Let me know if you can think of something!!

Comment: Lets approach this another way: why do you need to use mpl_connect? Why is line.get_xdata() not a valid solution?

Comment: well i built a GUI to plot some waveforms and i need to pick specific spots on the waveform figure. And i need to do this when i press a keyboard button. I am picking the P and S wave arrivals if you know what i mean. The time, these wave arrive on the seismograph. Search p and s wave arrivals, it will help you understand. And i need the combobox because i need to upload specific waveforms from a local file!!

Comment: You mean you want to click on the figure and get the x and y "specific spot" as well? That's fine, I don't mean that you can't use mpl_connect as well for another operation. A click will give focus back to the graph widget, so using mpl_connect for a click works. And in addition you can use tkinter's bind to look for program-wide keypresses.

Comment: well if i use the combobox and i select a value, it doesn't work cause it loses focus. This happens even if i click on the figure or even if i use takefocus=False on combobox. I don't know why. I solved it by using, plt.close(fig) , creating again a figure object , creating again a FigureCanvasTkAgg and connecting the figure again with fig.canvas.mpl_connect. All these in the 'myplot' function. I don't know if it is correct but it works!! Thanks for your time